# How to assign a specific number to all elements of matrix in vector<vector<int>> matrix_name without using for loop stuff?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

like we do this in array thing to assign a specific num to all elements of array-

```
vector<int> arr(n,-1);
```

So ya,above i mention how to do it in array but what about vector<vector> matrix_name?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n, std::vector<int>(n,-1));`

Comment: a vector that is element of another vector works in the exact same way as a vector. A vector is not an array btw

Comment: If you are working heavily with matrices and performance is a consideration, you definitely do not want to be using std::vector<std::vector<T>>.

Comment: Dear @goku-nohara. If you feel my answer helped you, could you please mark it as the solution.

Comment: How to do that @Tohnmeister, I do not know about it

Comment: @GokuNohara press the checkmark on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you can initialize a vector with a number of integers, given a default integer value, you can also initialize a vector with a number of other vectors, given a default value for that other vector. That way you can easily create a multidimensional vector.

Example:

```
int nr_of_rows = 30;
int nr_of_columns = 40;
std::vector matrix(nr_of_rows , std::vector(nr_of_columns , -1));
```

This creates a vector of 30 vectors of 40 integers with a default value of -1.

`matrix[2][17]` gives you vector with index 17 inside vector with index 2 of your matrix.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.

Comment: @Jbadminton Edited to provide more info.